# Insert to database error

Tags: android, database

This may be simple but 'm getting error so help me. I have list view and in each row i have button, when i click on button, it should take the title of that particular row and insert it into the database. When i click on the button it actually giving me the title, but i have problem with inserting that title to database.In the LazyAdapter class i have the below code

```
        Button play = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageArrow);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("play clicked!");
            String pgm_title = title.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("item selected: "+ pgm_title);

            CustomizedListView cust = new CustomizedListView();
            cust.InsertPlayItem(pgm_title);
        }
    });
```

And in the Main Activity i have this code. what is problem with this code?

```
     public void InsertPlayItem(String pgm_title) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getBaseContext());//getting error here
    db.insertPlayList(pgm_title);
}
```

getting below error:

```
12-26 16:03:00.751: W/dalvikvm(5861): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at com.example.devices.DatabaseHandler.insertPlayList(DatabaseHandler.java:422)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at com.example.programs.CustomizedListView.InsertPlayItem(CustomizedListView.java:137)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at com.example.programs.LazyAdapter$1.onClick(LazyAdapter.java:131)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-26 16:03:00.772: E/AndroidRuntime(5861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And my Database part:

```
            public void insertPlayList(String playname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(play_list, playname);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(Personalize, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: Please specify the problem you are facing. What happens after calling db.insertPlayList(pgm_title); method?

Comment: try to use Activityname.this in place of getbasecontext(); .may be you can solve this problem.otherwise post the error here.

Comment: @Google i used But getting error. See my logcat error i posted

Comment: @Brinda-user1594986 ya i see that i think arash is told the right way so try to use that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got .. In the LazyAdapter class only i did like this.

```
       Button play = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageArrow);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("play clicked!");
            String pgm_title = title.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("item selected: "+ pgm_title);
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
            db.insertPlayList(pgm_title);
                        }
         }
```